# Web Essentials Bundle Angular scripts error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I've tried to bundle my AngularJS files using Web Essentials, and when I reference my bundled (and not minified, just bundled) JavaScript file I get error,

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PublicNotificationsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

And without bundling everything works fine.

Note I'm injecting my dependencies to controller like this:

```
    publicApp.angularModule.controller('PublicNotificationsCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', 'notificationsService', 'profileBasicInfoService', function ($scope, $window, $location, $rootScope, notificationsService, profileBasicInfoService) {

    }]);
```

My question is can I bundle Angular scripts with Web Essentials ? (if I can how can I fix this problem)

Comment: Are the scripts listed in the correct order in the `.bundle` file?

Comment: That was the problem, thanks :)